# How can I solve the 'cannot delete password' error when using the jupyter extension in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have been using the jupyter extension in vscode without an issue for well over a year now. Today when I try to run any cell in a jupyter notebook all I get is a very generic error popping up in the corner of the vscode window saying: 'Cannot delete password (Source: Jupyter (Extension))'. I am not trying to use any password protection. This is a local project running locally.

I have tried:

- uninstall and reinstall the extension
- uninstall and reinstall vscode
- successfully ran the jupyter notebook as a server in chrome browser

I can find no information on this error anywhere. Does anyone know what it is referring to? Does anyone know how or where I can find logs or messages with more information? How can I solve this error?

[image]

- OS: Opensuse (Tumbleweed)
- vscode: version 1.56.2
- jupyter extension: v2021.6.832593372

Comment: Check **Jupyter Server**, is it local or remote?

Comment: Server has been local but it is an issue with the jupyter.jupyterServerType setting. I linked the bug report in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the user settings
2. Pull up the settings specifically for the jupyter extension
3. Switch the jupyter.jupyterServerType value to "local" in the the workspace and the user settings
4. Now the cells should run as expected.

This is only a workaround for a bug in the extension. see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/5934).